# How do I get the content of the <title> tag from a requested html using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I need to get the title of a webpage based on its URL. The way I did it is using jQuery:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $.ajax({url: 'http://www.google.com', success: function (data) {
        console.log($('title', $(data)).html());
    }});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

However it somehow fails and it only returns an `undefined` value and an error saying:

```
"Failed to load resource file:///C:/images/srpr/logo4w.png"
```

Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: Google.com will not let you do that cause of `"X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN"` BTW what's returned inside `data`, only a title? I think not.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan: If that's the case, then how come if I change `'title'` into for example `'.gbxx'`, then the return value is correctly `"<legend class="gbxx"> ... </div>"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsbin.com/owavux/2/edit

(Works cause of `SAMEORIGIN`)

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'http://jsbin.com/owavux/1/edit',
  success: function (data) {
    var title = $(data).filter("title").text();
    alert( title );
    // To set that title to your current page do like:
    document.title = title;
  }
});
```

Comment: Yes, your code works. But the only difference is that instead using `$(data)` as a context of a jQuery, you append the query as a filter. So what's the difference of these two different ways?

Comment: @trVoldemort data returns the whole HTML, therefore using `filter` you actually process the whole returned HTML searching for the `title` tag.